# How java Callable interface executing multi-tasking

Tags: java, multithreading

[Here is the java.util.concurrent.FutureTask doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), and here am using lambda expression without creating Callable implementation class, and here is My code just want to test how callable interface works but result make me unsatisfied.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class CallableTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FutureTask<Integer> ft = new FutureTask<Integer>((Callable<Integer>)() -> {
            int i = 0;
            for(; i < 100; i++){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t"+ i);
            }
            return i;
        });
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + i);
            if(i == 20){
                new Thread(ft, "有返回值的线程").start();
                new Thread(ft, "会不会执行呢？").start();
            }
        }
        try{
            System.out.println("The result of ft is " + ft.get());
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

result show thread made by `new Thread(ft, "会不会执行呢？").start();` never execute no matter iterator times was 100 or whatever. that's why? I have googled this question, but they all said using ThreadPool, but i think if these two simple thread can not work threadpool will not too.

Answer (score 2):

`FutureTask` maintains a `state` with the following transitions:

```
 * Possible state transitions:
 * NEW -> COMPLETING -> NORMAL
 * NEW -> COMPLETING -> EXCEPTIONAL
 * NEW -> CANCELLED
 * NEW -> INTERRUPTING -> INTERRUPTED
```

If the state is not `NEW`, it's `run` method just returns:

```
    public void run() {
        if (state != NEW ||
            !UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset,
                                     null, Thread.currentThread()))
            return;
        ....
    }
```

Therefore a separate `FutureTask` instance is needed for each Thread as `ft` has a state which is not `NEW` after the first threads execution.

The following code executes both threads:

```
    import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
    import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

    public class FutureTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FutureTask<Integer> ft = getFutureTask();
        FutureTask<Integer> ft2 = getFutureTask();
        new Thread(ft, "有返回值的线程").start();
        new Thread(ft2, "会不会执行呢？").start();
        try{
            System.out.println("The result of ft is " + ft.get());
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        try{
            System.out.println("The result of ft2 is " + ft2.get());
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }

    private static FutureTask<Integer> getFutureTask() {
        return new FutureTask<Integer>((Callable<Integer>)() -> {
            int i = 0;
            for(; i < 100; i++){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t"+ i);
            }
            return i;
        });
    }
```

Comment: If i have to instantiate an FutureTask every time  for each task, it should not be defined as multithread because multiple FutureTask instances are not served for one Task.eh, here i want to make some amendment on your answer, i think if Callable interface has been implemented and each FutureTask  put this implementation as constructor parameter, ok, multithread idea appears.